# Python & MSSQL: Python Code to Delete All Rows of Data in MSSQL Table

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I'm scripting in a Python environment.  I have successfully written a pandas dataframe to a table in MSSQL.

I want to use Python code to delete all rows in my MSSQL table.  I know the SQL syntax to do this (shown below).

```
DELETE FROM [LON].[dbo].[MREPORT]
```

BUT how do I incorporate the SQL syntax in my python code so I can run the code in my python environment and have it delete all rows in the MSSQL table?

Comment: You've already connected python the this db, so why can't you just send the SQL you already have made?

Comment: apologies, I don't understand ... the SQL I have made in python is just read_sql statement pulling in data from MSSQL ... I don't know syntax for delete rows

Answer (score 5):

Are you using pyobc ?

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={<your_driver>};
                       SERVER=<your_server>
                       DATABASE=<your_database>;
                       UID=<user>;
                       PWD=<passwd>')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE <your_table>")
```

Comment: something like that should do it

Comment: yes, that's exactly the syntax I used to connect ... and I did import both pyodbc and pypyodbc